# Show items cells vertically in collection view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

It's first time i am using collectionView. where my cells are presented like C1,C2,C3.
But i want it like

C1

C2

C3

instead. is there any property like position of cell or something. Looks a silly one but couldn't figure it out.

pls help.

Comment: You can change your data to reflect the way you need to present it.

Comment: i am showing photos under it. How can i do so?

Comment: If there is only one cell on each line why don't you use table view ?

Comment: Do you mean to show only one item in a row? If so you can do by either restricting the frame size of collection view.

Comment: yup I want to show only one photo at a time in one row.

Comment: Ok. You can build custom cell which has one ImageView and set the size such that only one cell from collection view will be displayed.

Comment: @user2071152 I have tried reducing the size of frame and it does the  trick automatically by shifting the next photo to new row.

Comment: guys the image that i am getting is of smaller size that i am retrieving from CoreDB. How to get the actual size of the image and show the full image on CollectionView.

Comment: If you want your data displayed vertically in one column... then why not use a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout

```
      UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout;
      layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
      layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
      layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;
      layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame), 60);
      layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 0, 10, 10);
      [collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:NO];`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set CollectionView Scroll Direction Vertical to Horizontal.

[image]